# Why does this bash regex using variables passed through a function work in one case but not the other?

Tags: regex, bash

Using the following bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export SSLPROTOCOL="-all +TLSv1.2"
export SSLCIPHERSUITE="HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!AES128"

# Set with quotes on purpose for this question
SSLPROTOCOL_PATTERN="^([+-]{1}[[:alnum:]]{3}(v[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?)?[[:space:]]?)+$"
SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN="^([!+\-]?[\-[:alnum:]]+:?)+$"

# $SSLCIPHERSUITE successfully validates if you pass regex directly
if ! [[ $SSLCIPHERSUITE =~ ^([!+\-]?[\-[:alnum:]]+:?)+$ ]]; then
  echo "Doesn't match"
else
  echo "Matches"
fi

validate() {
  if ! [[ $1 =~ $2 ]]; then
    echo "Parameter value '$1' does not match the pattern $2"
  else
    echo "Parameter value '$1' validated."
  fi
}

# SSLPROTOCOL Passes when passing regex as argument to function.
validate "$SSLPROTOCOL" "$SSLPROTOCOL_PATTERN"
# $SSLCIPHERSUITE Does not pass when passing regex as argument to function.
validate "$SSLCIPHERSUITE" "$SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN"
```

I get the output:

```
➜ bash simple-test.sh
Matches
Parameter value '-all +TLSv1.2' validated.
Parameter value 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:!AES128' does not match the pattern ^([!+\-]?[\-[:alnum:]]+:?)+$
```

As the comments explain:

- `SSLCIPHERSUITE` validates against the regex successfully if you do it directly
- `SSLCIPHERSUITE` does not validate if you pass the regex as an argument into a function.
- `SSLPROTOCOL`, however, does validate when passed as an argument into the function.

**I know that this will work if you remove the quotes for the `SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN` regex and escape the `()` characters**, like so:

`SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN=^\([!+\-]?[\-[:alnum:]]+:?\)+$`

**My question is why?** Why does `SSLPROTOCOL_PATTERN` work originally and `SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN` does not? Why does one need no quotes and the other works fine with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're escaping a character (`-`) that shouldn't be escaped (and using the wrong type of quotes, though you can get away with it in this context). Use this instead:

```
SSLCIPHERSUITE_PATTERN='^([!+-]?[-[:alnum:]]+:?)+$'
```

To portably include `-` in a bracket expression in any tool you must put it at the start or end of the bracket expression, where you already have it. In some tools you can put it elsewhere in the bracket expression but then have to escape it but YMMV doing that and there's no reason to do it.

As for why it works in:

```
if ! [[ $SSLCIPHERSUITE =~ ^([!+\-]?[\-[:alnum:]]+:?)+$ ]]; then
```

my guess is bash is consuming the escape when parsing the code before using the resultant regexp in the comparison, again you should remove the `\` though.

The escapes are the real problem in this case but in general - always use single quotes around all strings (including scripts) unless you NEED double quotes or no quotes, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

As for why you must not quote the literal regexp in the comparison, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382054/133219.

Comment: `using the wrong type of quotes` - this is not exact because in this particular case, single quotes and double quotes have the same effect.

Comment: @Philippe - that's why I downplayed that aspect but being able to get away with using double quotes in some context doesn't mean you should use them. People using double quotes instead of single (or no quotes instead of either) is one of the most common sources of bugs in shell scripts so it's worth pointing that out to anyone using double quotes when there's no need to use them instead of single quotes.

Comment: I agree with the principle. But saying `using the wrong type of quotes` can be misleading in this context because single and double quotes have the same effect. You can verify with `printf '\-'` and `printf "\-"`

Comment: Thank you. That works. Thanks as well for the continued discussion @Philippe, that adds great clarifying details.